# Question on Mean value theorem involving ln

Tags: real-analysis

Show that for all $x\in\mathbf{R}$, $|e^x-1-x|\le \frac{x^2}{2}e^{|x|}$

This can be written as

$-(\frac{x^2}{2}e^{|x|})\le e^x-1-x \le (\frac{x^2}{2}e^{|x|})$

I have started by taking $\ln$ on both sides.

$\ln \frac{2}{x^2 e^{|x|}} \le \ln(e^x-1-x) \le \ln \frac{x^2}{2}e^{|x|}$

$\ln 2-2\ln x-|x|  \le \ln(e^x-1-x) \le 2\ln x+|x|-\ln2$

We get 2 inequalities,

$\ln 2-2\ln x-|x|  \le \ln(e^x-1-x)$ and
  $\ln(e^x-1-x) \le 2\ln x+|x|-\ln2$

Afterwards, I am a bit lost.

Comment: Write down Taylor series, even if that might not be a method that is allowed to use, it might help you finding the direction to solve the problem using ordinary mean value theorem.

Comment: Taylor series for $\frac{x^2}{2}e^{|x|}$?

Comment: You can plug in $|x|$ to the expansion of $e^x$ and multiply by $\frac{x^2}{2}$

Comment: I shall try that, if it is still a problem, I shall revert back to you.Thanks for this by the way.

Comment: I get $(\frac{x^2}{2}(1+|x|+\frac{|x(x-1|}{2}+...)$ for the Taylor expansion, then what?